# Notepad++ doesn't open .TXT files automatically. File association is set in Windows 10

Tags: notepad++

In Windows 10 I have the .TXT file extension set to be opened by NotePad++. I also have the Command Line processor SETPATHEXT set to .TXT. If I invoke NotePad++ and select a .txt file from the Open menu the file opens OK. But if I type (or select from File Manager) MyFile.txt, NotePad++ executes but opens a blank page.
Thanks for any attention to this.
afk

Comment: Hello, what version of N++? Do other types of files open correctly if you associate their extensions?

Comment: Hi, I can't find the ver number but the .exe date is 08/15/2023. All other files work ok. If the filename extension is associated with N++ and also included in SETPATHEXT then it loads automatically into N++ with only the filename entered at the prompt.

Comment: I've since eliminated .TXT from the global environment string SETPATHEXE and rebooted but the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

After I figured out how to get the debug info I noticed that the command line was empty when invoking NPP. The culprit turned out to be a missing calling parameter in the Windows registry.

\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile\shell\open\command || "c:\Program Files\NotePad++\NotePad++.exe"
should have had the parameter "%1" postpended to the link.

. . . \Notepad++.exe" "%1"

Thanks for your time and interest.
Austin Kelly

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open the Windows Explorer file manager.
- Right-click on a file with `.txt` extension.
- Select `Open with...`
- Select `Choose another app`.
- If *Notepad++* is not shown, choose `More apps`.
- Select *Notepad++*.
- **Select `Always use this app to open .txt files`.**
- Click `OK`.

Comment: Hi, I had done that earlier but just to be certain I performed all of the above steps again and found that the settings were already where they should be. Each time I right-clicked on Open the same thing happened - N++ executes but opens a blank page. But when I tried either of the options which utilize the word "Edit" the .txt file opens correctly in N++. We might be on to something.      Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Try removing Notepad++ as the default editor by making another app, e.g., Notepad, the default, as above. Then set NPP as default again.

Comment: I tried removing Notepad++ as default substituting WordPad and WordPad worked as expected. But when I reinstalled NotePad++ as default the original problem returned. I also crosschecked the default app in Windows Settings as I was changing them back and forth and each change was picked up on the Settings page as it was made in File Manager.